# Is "still it means nothing" correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

I found this sentence in a chat message:
"I love her but still it means nothing"

I feel something is wrong with it, but I couldn't figure out what it is.

Comment: It means the poor guy is pretty confused.  The main thing "wrong" (aside from the sentiment) is a missing comma.

Answer (score 1):

Given the right context, it is correct. Assuming the writer was a native English speaker, it may have been used in the correct context.

"but still" is somewhat equivalent to "yet", the phrase could have been written:

> I love her yet it means nothing

A comma is not necessary in either case.